# Как работают битовые операции на Long в Java?

Tags: java

У меня есть следующий код:

```
@Test
public void simpleTest() {
    long x = 0;
    x |= 3L;
    System.out.println(showBits(x));
}

private String showBits(long x) {
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < 64; i++) {
        builder.append((x & (1 << i)) > 0 ? "1" : "0");
    }
    return builder.reverse().toString();
}
```

В результате я ожидал увидеть такую последовательность: `00...011`, но на деле получилось:

```
0000000000000000000000000000001100000000000000000000000000000011
```

Я понимаю, что в `int` 32 бита, а в `long` 64. Мне непонятно, почему в `long` типе обновляются оператором или каждые 32 бита, а не только первые.

Если вывести через `System.out.println(x)`, то будет 3. А почему тогда дублируется тройка в битовом представлении?

Кажется, что ошибка где-то в цикле при выполннении операции И.

Comment: Вы просто `int` по кругу гоняете, поменяйте на `(1L << i)`

Comment: @Serodv Точно! Спасибо, не заметил(